# Injecting parent classes from other libraries with Guice

Tags: java, groovy, guice

I am trying to use Guice (4.0) to bootstrap dependencies for my executable from inside my main driver class (perhaps this is a Guice anti-pattern?):

```
// Groovy pseudo-code
// This Buzz class is located in a 3rd party lib that I don't have access to
class Buzz {
    int foobaz
    Whistlefeather whistlefeather

    // other stuff, include constructor, setters and getters
}

class MyApp extends Buzz {
    @Inject
    DatabaseClient dbClient

    @Inject
    FizzRestClient fizzClient

    static void main(String[] args) {
        MyApp app = Guice.createInjector(new MyAppModule()).getInstance(MyApp)
        app.run()
    }

    private void run() {
        // Do your thing, little app!
    }
}

class MyAppModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    void configure() {
        bind(DatabaseClient).to(DefaultDatabaseClient)
        bind(FizzRestClient).to(DefaultFizzRestClient)

        // But how do I configure MyApp's 'foobaz' and 'whistlefeather'
        // properties? Again, I don't have access to the code, so I
        // can't annotate them with @Inject, @Named, etc.
    }
}
```

So my problem is that `MyApp` actually extends a base object living in a 3rd party (OSS) JAR. This base class (`Buzz`) is not set up for use with Javax Inject or Guice. But I would like Guice to be able to configure its `foobaz` and `whistlefeather` properties.... any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and inject any bean with a `@Provide` method in a Guice module. For example:

```
@Provides
MyApp externalService(DatabaseClient dbClient, Whistlefeather wf) {
    MyApp app = new MyApp();
    app.setDatabaseCLient(dbClient);
    app.setWhitlefeature(wf);
    return app;
}
```

See [@Provides](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ProvidesMethods)

Comment: Thanks @Jeremie B (+1) - do you mind updating your answer to include my specific use case (and classes)? I ask because I'm not sure if you fully understand what I'm asking (or, more likely, I just don't understand what you're saying!). I'm worried that because `MyApp` extends `Buzz`, and because `MyApp` is where the Guice injector is being created (the "root" of my dependency graph), that your suggested approach will not work...

Comment: i haven't seen your `MyApp` was extending `Buzz`. This buzz doesn't have setters ?

Comment: Thanks @Jeremie B (+1 again) - yes it has ctor and both getters and setters for those properties. Any ideas?

Comment: I have updated the example. But you can't have "partial binding". in your case, you have to call the setters yourself

Comment: Thanks @Jeremie B (+1) - what do you mean by "partial binding"? Is that where Guice Assisted Inject comes into play?

Comment: partial binding, i though about a class not fully annotated with @Inject. AssistedInject doesn't fit your use case: it's principally when you have parameters which are only known at runtime, to generate a factory. In your case, all the fields are managed by Guice, It's not worth the effort